# How to reduce Roblox lag on a possibly Potato PC

Tags: performance, roblox

I'm looking for ways to further reduce/remove lag from my possibly potato PC. I did reduce most of the quality settings from the Roblox studio, and only plays games on lowest possible settings. But, at 9am in Korea, it runs at 100~200 pings, and during the evening it jumps to 2000~3000 pings.

Is there a way to fix this morning and evening gap of lag? As only in the evening am I able to play, and having literal 5 second delay disables gameplay whatsoever. This wouldn't matter so much if it was mostly things like Obbies, but this is for Rogue Lineage, a game where timing and quick response is key.

Is there a way I can further reduce lag on my PC? And please keep the "upgrade your PC" opinion to the minimum, as it is not a very viable option for me.

My PC specs are:

- Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3770 CPU @ 3.40GHz 3.40 GHz
- RAM: 4.00GB (3.48 Available)
- System: 32 Bit, x64 based processor

(This was all translated from Korean to English, so ask me to provide further information in the comments.)
EDIT: Thanks! But can you provide further information of about what level of graphics is the golden spot?
Also, yes, it's like its on a timer, only during evenings does it jump to 2k ping. During about 11, it's only 90. If this is a network problem, is there a way I can make it better? I'm just a kid so...

Comment: Sounds like a network problem not a computer problem

Comment: Yes, ping usually isn't your fault, and ROBLOX servers have a habit of not responding to people for seconds at a time due to the heavy load. Is it consistently 2000+ ping in the evening?

Comment: I might add that running the game at the lowest possible setting will actively reduce your FPS - Graphics Settings 1 will constantly unload and load new surroundings as you move, which is incredibly laggy.

Comment: Thanks, ya'll! Ill try running the game at a better setting, but what level is the golden spot? Also, yes, its like it's on a timer - It only lags in evenings and during 11 and such the ping drops to 90. Is there a way I can tamper with the wifi router or something if this is a network problem?

Comment: Again, the Roblox database is terrible when it comes to holding so many users at once. The excessive ping could be because more kids play at that time (different places have different time) than at morning in your place.

Answer (score 1):

That's not your computer, That is your internet connection! Your computer will lag a little bit on Roblox. But ping is how long it takes for your input to go to the Roblox servers. The answer to this question is sadly is that you need to pay for a better internet plan. Or you could try plugging a Ethernet cable right into your computer to get somewhat better internet. It could also be where you live or a problem at roblox!

Answer (score 0):

It depends regarding the game you are playing and your internet connection. If your internet connection is fine, the game may be very big with a very detailed map. Try lowering your graphic settings in roblox from the menu. Lowering graphic settings in heavy roblox games like Phantom Forces and others may require a good graphics card. Many games though that need good graphics card and others may state that in the game description.
Your 4GB RAM, Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3770 CPU @ 3.40GHz 3.40 GHz Processor are good specs. The thing now may be your internet or Graphics card. I run heavy roblox games with an AMD Ryzen 5 3550H on laptop 16GB RAM. ( RAM not really necessary for roblox but i run beamng drive too) Soo yea, check your Graphics card, try lowering your graphic settings and if your internet connection is bad, lower your graphics to avoid much lag.

Hope this helped.